# Powershell script to get list of subscriptions for provided user name

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to get list of subscriptions for a user.
In order to execute "Get-AzureRMSubscription" we need to login first.
But my intention is to get the list of subscriptions the user is associated to.

Comment: you can use username and password to run command`Login-azurermaccount`.

Answer (score 4):

You need first to login, only then can you run `Get-AzureRmSubscription`

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmSubscription
```

this will give you a list of all subscriptions that the user you logged in as, can access.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Thats what I ended up doing.